# How to expand memoization table in J

Tags: j

Previous discussion is on [Memoization in J](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31724213/6088109) which doesn't answer the issue. The problem is that using memoization `M.` somehow makes the program much slower.

I encountered the same problem. Consider this example:

```
collatz =: (%&2)`(1+3&*)@.(2&|)
countchain =: 3 : 0 M.
  echo 'xx ' , ": y
  if. (1=y) do. (1) else. (1 + countchain collatz y) end.
)
```

The `countchain` above will tell you how many collatz steps it took for the number to get to 1. The `echo` part will show you if the memoization works. And, indeed, it appears to be working:

```
   countchain"0 (1 2 3 4 5)
xx 1
xx 2
xx 3
xx 10
xx 5
xx 16
xx 8
xx 4
1 2 8 3 6
```

As you can see, the `countchain` method is not repeated for the same number. However, when I tried it on longer sequence of numbers (e.g. `(1+i.1000)`, and pasting the output to a text file, I observed that there are lots of repetitions. Which mean the program was executed on values it has seen before. I also noticed that the repetition appeared exactly after 32 values have been executed, so the problem appear to be from memory. The [documentation](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/mcapdot) also mentioned that "The size of the table used to record arguments and results is not under user control."  Is there really no way to alleviate this problem?

Comment: If `M.` isn’t letting you do what you want to do, you can always roll your own. Make a list of inputs, check it for dupes (`i =. seen_values i. y`) and if it’s new (`i = #y`), calculate a result, else take it from previously calculated results (`i { previous_results`). When you have a new value, make sure to append it to `seen_values` and the new result to `previous_results`. The dyad `i.` is very fast on integer arguments.

Comment: I've never gotten any use out of `M.`, even after the discussion on my question, so I'm curious to see if this helps.